# How to overlay plots with different dates?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I would like to overlay two plots that are in different date or time. To do so, I have implemented the following code.

```
import random
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px

df = pd.DataFrame({'DATE_TIME':pd.date_range('2022-11-01', '2022-11-06 23:00:00',freq='20min'),
                   'ID':[random.randrange(1, 20) for n in range(430)]})
df['VALUE1'] = [random.uniform(110, 160) for n in range(430)]
df['VALUE2'] = [random.uniform(50, 80) for n in range(430)]
df['INSPECTION'] = df['DATE_TIME'].dt.day

df['MODE'] = np.select([df['INSPECTION']==1, df['INSPECTION'].isin([2,3])], ['A', 'B'], 'C')
#print(df)
machine15 = df[df.ID==15]
machine15_inspection_1 = machine15[machine15.INSPECTION==1]
machine15_inspection_2 = machine15[machine15.INSPECTION==2]


fig1 = px.line(machine15_inspection_1, x="DATE_TIME", y=["VALUE1","VALUE2"], facet_col='INSPECTION',
                         facet_row_spacing=0.1,
                         facet_col_spacing=0.09,
                         markers=True)

fig2 = px.line(machine15_inspection_2, x="DATE_TIME", y=["VALUE1","VALUE2"],facet_col='INSPECTION',
                         facet_row_spacing=0.1,
                         facet_col_spacing=0.09,
                         markers=True)

fig2.update_traces(opacity=0.6)
fig1.add_traces(
    list(fig2.select_traces())
)
fig1.update_xaxes(matches=None, showticklabels=True)

fig1.show()
```

And then, obtained the plot below:

[image]

How should I twist my code so that I can overlay `VALUE1` and `VALUE2`?

Or, in other words, how can I **overlay fig1 and fig2**.

Comment: It is unclear what kind of final output you are hoping for. id and inspection code are extraction criteria? Is there anything else?

Comment: @r-beginners I would like to overlay fig1 and fig2

Comment: That's not possible as long as we have different time series in my opinion. For example, if you draw with an index and later update it as a string of ticks, the index will be missing even as a string of time series data.

Comment: As you would with time series data that does has not consecutive dates, you can alter both sets of data to the same index. You can use tick text and tick values to make the axis show whatever you would like. There are always ways to create a spurious correlation. For example, if you wanted both of the dates that were originally the date axis for the data, you can add these to `customdata` and include them in the `hovertemplate`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would a `secondary x-axis` work for you? Like this?

[image]

In that case you can set up a figure with multiple axes like this:

```
fig=make_subplots(
        specs=[[{"secondary_y": True}]])
fig.update_layout(xaxis2= {'anchor': 'y', 'overlaying': 'x', 'side': 'top'})
```

And then make a few tweaks with:

```
fig1.for_each_trace(lambda t: fig.add_trace(t, secondary_y=False))
fig2.for_each_trace(lambda t: fig.add_trace(t, secondary_y=False))
fig.data[2].update(xaxis='x2')
fig.data[3].update(xaxis='x2')
```

There are numerous ways you can put together that last part. Let me know if this is something you can use, or if anything is unclear.

#### Complete code:

```
import random
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

df = pd.DataFrame({'DATE_TIME':pd.date_range('2022-11-01', '2022-11-06 23:00:00',freq='20min'),
                   'ID':[random.randrange(1, 20) for n in range(430)]})
df['VALUE1'] = [random.uniform(110, 160) for n in range(430)]
df['VALUE2'] = [random.uniform(50, 80) for n in range(430)]
df['INSPECTION'] = df['DATE_TIME'].dt.day

df['MODE'] = np.select([df['INSPECTION']==1, df['INSPECTION'].isin([2,3])], ['A', 'B'], 'C')
#print(df)
machine15 = df[df.ID==15]
machine15_inspection_1 = machine15[machine15.INSPECTION==1]
machine15_inspection_2 = machine15[machine15.INSPECTION==2]


fig1 = px.line(machine15_inspection_1, x="DATE_TIME", y=["VALUE1","VALUE2"], facet_col='INSPECTION',
                         facet_row_spacing=0.1,
                         facet_col_spacing=0.09,
                         markers=True)

fig2 = px.line(machine15_inspection_2, x="DATE_TIME", y=["VALUE1","VALUE2"],facet_col='INSPECTION',
                         facet_row_spacing=0.1,
                         facet_col_spacing=0.09,
                         markers=True)

fig2.update_traces(opacity=0.6)

fig=make_subplots(
        specs=[[{"secondary_y": True}]])
fig.update_layout(xaxis2= {'anchor': 'y', 'overlaying': 'x', 'side': 'top'})
# fig.datafig = fig1.data + fig2.data
# fig.update_traces(list(fig1.select_traces()))
fig1.for_each_trace(lambda t: fig.add_trace(t, secondary_y=False))
fig2.for_each_trace(lambda t: fig.add_trace(t, secondary_y=False))
fig.data[2].update(xaxis='x2')
fig.data[3].update(xaxis='x2')

fig.show()
```

Comment: Thanks secondary y axis worked for me like a charm